# Insert multiple rows in MYSQL DB via PDO exec()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Running this on server side results only in ONE row added to DB:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();                       
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO players_map_test (player_id, tile_id, tile_type, tile_level, tile_health) 
    VALUES 
    ('$player_id', 1, 0, 0, 1),
    ('$player_id', 2, 0, 0, 1),
    ('$player_id', 3, 0, 0, 1)"
    );                      
$pdo->commit();
```

How do I add all three rows?

I am trying to avoid the prepared statement and further binding for simplicity as all values are server side and thus trusted.

Comment: And how do you check that there is only one row added?

Comment: I can see only one row (first one) in this table in phpMyAdmin

Comment: There is no way that this query ads one row without two others. Are you sure you run this query? Do you run this query with that one row in table already? If yes, remove this row from table first

Comment: Check is there some unique constraint or PK that you violates.

Comment: >> Do you run this query with that one row in table already? No, the table is does not contain the row prior to insertion. I will try to insert rows one by one via separate exec() command and see what happens.

Comment: @ Evgeny: this might be it, '$player_id' is set as PK. Shall I not have it as a PK but rather as something else? The table is designed to store map some map tile info for players and will be queried based on the player_id value.

Comment: You should have a generic id column as the primary key and player_id as an indexed integer column

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in primary key violation. Introduced a row_id column and turned the primary key value into index instead.